# PHP Associative Arrays - Replace --> with "as"

Tags: php, sql, arrays, key, associative

I know there must an easy and efficient way to do this.

I have an array like this:

```
       $fields = array( "EVENT_ID" => "Event Id" ,
            "EVENT_NAME"           => "Name",
            "EVENT_CLASSIFICATION" => "Classification",
            "DESCRIPTION"          => "Description",
            "START_TIME"           => "Start Time",
            "END_TIME"             => "End Time"
           );
```

I would like to convert this as this query:

```
              Select 
                   "EVENT_ID" as "Event ID",
                   "EVENT_NAME" as "Name", 
                   ...
              from
                   ...
```

Don't want to put this in Loop. PHP has a lot array handling functions and this must be easy. I am new to php.

Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry to disappoint you, but if you are afraid of loops, forget about arrays :)

Comment: As well as software development in general, excepting maybe Prolog, SQL and functional-only languages.

Comment: @AndrejsCainikovs, Forget Arrays!?! Whats better alternatives? :-)

Comment: But you loop arrays arrrggg :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply build your query's string by looping through your values.

```
$query = '';
foreach($fields as $k => $v)
    $query .= '"' . $k . '" as "' . $v . '",';
echo $query;
```

Note that this will leave a trailing comma. If you want to remove it, you can use

```
$query = rtrim($query, ',');
```

[**Live example**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/IVzn3L)

Answer (score 5):

I heavily suggest loops!

```
$sel = array();
foreach($fields as $key => $val) {
  $sel[] = '`'.$key.'` AS `'.$val.'`';
}
$sel = implode(',', $sel);
```

Comment: Thanks! Not possible without loops?

Comment: It is, see [Rockets answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10195953/612202), but that's just a wrapper for a loop too. So it doesn't really matter. (although I find that harder too read than a loop)

Comment: Looks good, but I would go with `$sel[] = "'$key' as '$val'"`.

Comment: Those backticks are there that you can use reserved mysql words as you want.

Answer (score 3):

A loop is (probably) the way to go here, but you can do it without one.  Using [`array_map`](http://php.net/array_map).

```
$sql = implode(',', array_map(function($v, $k){
    return "`$k` AS `$v`";
}, $fields, array_keys($fields)));
```

NOTE you can only pass functions like this in PHP 5.3+.  If you're using 5.2, you can use [`create_function`](http://php.net/create_function).

```
$sql = implode(',', array_map(create_function('$v, $k', 'return "`$k` AS `$v`";'), $fields, array_keys($fields)));
```

Comment: Thanks! It looks good. Which one is efficient and fast? Loop or this one?

Comment: @KevinRave functions like `array_map()` use loops under the bonnet anyway, there won't be much in it. That said, a C++ loop is likely more efficient than a PHP one, so this is probably slightly better. But so little difference that it's not even noticeable unless you have hundreds of thousands of items. Although this does have the added overhead of calling a function on every iteration of the loop underneath, so YMMV.

Answer (score 2):

If you're on 5.3, you can use [`array_reduce`](http://php.net/array_reduce) with closures (plain old functions work too, but `foreach` would be shorter then):

```
$sql = array_reduce(array_keys($fields), function(&$result, $key) use ($fields) {
  if (!is_null($result)) $result .= ",\n";
  return "{$result}'{$key}' AS '{$fields[$key]}'";
});
```

[Try online](http://codepad.viper-7.com/OMA1Wq)

Comment: I'd prefer `array_map` for this situation, but this works too.  +1